# Markov chain theorem to prove positive recurrence

Tags: probability, probability-theory, markov-chains

I need help with this problem that uses the following result:

Let $P$ and $P'$ be probability transition matrices of irreducible chains that are identical except for a finite number of terms in the first row. So $p_{0j} \neq p'_{0j}$ for some $j$, $j\leq k$, $k < \infty$. Then all the states of $P$ are positive recurrent if and only if all the states in $P$ are positiev recurrent.

This is my problem I want to solve

Use this result and what you know about another Markov chain to find conditions under which the following chain is positive recurrent:

$$\begin{bmatrix} .2 & .4 & .1 & .3 & &\cdots \\ q & 0 & p & 0 & & \cdots\\ 0 & q & 0 & p & & &\\  & \ddots & & \ddots & \end{bmatrix}$$

Here $pq > 0$ and $ p + q = 1$.

I tried many things like changing the first row to just one $1$ but I guess my thinking process is not great for positive recurrence. I guess I need to change the first row to make it positive recurrent but I do not know what conditions I will get.

Also I think this is similar to gambler's ruin problem matrix.

Comment: I think you must mean: "Then all the states of $P$ are positive recurrent if and only if all the states in $P$ are **positive** recurrent," right?

Comment: Yes you are  right

Comment: Are there any other conditions on $p$ or $q$? In particular, do we know that $q > p$ (or the converse)?

Comment: No we need to find the conditions on $p$ and $q$ to make it positive recurrent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint 1:

> The theorem you cite allows you to manipulate the first row, or at least its first four entries. How might you do that to obtain something familiar?

Hint 2:

> What familiar chain would you have if the first row was $[0 \quad  1 \quad  0 \quad 0 \quad \dots]$?

Hint 3:

> With the change referenced in Hint 2, you'd have a $p \uparrow, q \downarrow$ random walk on the nonnegative integers. What do you know about positive recurrence of that chain?

Solution:

> The $p \uparrow, q \downarrow$ random walk on the nonnegative integers is positive recurrent if, and only if, $q > p$. (If $q = p$, then the chain is null recurrent, and if $q < p$, then the chain is transient.)

Comment: In hint 2, Do you mean $[1, 0, 0, 0, ...]$ instead of $[0, 1, 0, 0, 0, \cdots]$? For gambler's ruin problem ?

Comment: I meant the one I wrote, but note that the theorem you cited in your problem text indicates that it doesn't matter which one you would pick, as far as this problem is concerned. If you choose $[1, 0, \dots]$, you're envisioning a random walk on $\mathbb Z_{\geq 0}$ that gets stuck at $0$ once it reaches it. If you choose $[0, 1, \dots]$, you're envisioning a walk that never gets stuck, but rather bounces back up to $1$ once it reaches $0$ (and from there, continues by stepping either to $0$ or $2$ with respective probabilities $q$ and $p$).